# Why doesn't reconfigure tool update modules list?

Tags: lyx, modules

I am using LyX ver. 2.0.1 and would like to use the enumitem.module. This module is in my `C:\Program Files\LyX20\Resources\layouts` folder, but does not show up as an available module to add when selecting `Documents->Settings...->Modules`. I have tried running `Tools->Reconfigure`, then, restarting LyX, but this does not add the module. I have seen references to adding the module manually to the `lyxmodules.lst` file, but I am not sure what information I would need to add to list file.

Does anyone know what more I need to do to get this module added?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Do you have any modules in `Documents->Settings...->Modules` at all? If yes, is there some module called "Customisable Lists (enumitem)"?